# Are "Do this calculations for me" question allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, policy

I have a problem to be solved ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554896/10196)) and an answer that brings all the necessary calculation steps ([here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/72682/10196)). I can't do the calculations myself because I don't have enough knowledge and skills. I went through cited answer seven times and still fail to even start.

Does this mean that I should close my question as being homework-like?

This meta question is similar to [my previous meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12886/10196) with the difference that I was asking there whether I can ask for helping me find proper equations and solution. Here solution is given and only calculations, that are far beyond my abilities, must be performed. I guess that this mandates my main site question as off-topic. Am I correct?

As suggested in [my previous meta question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12886/10196), I have used chat to seek for help, but no one responded to me.

Comment: I suppose that the calculation (which you're expecting in the form of an answer) is not particularly useful to anyone except you, and thus this question doesn't have any value for anyone except you. We tend to close such questions (the ones which aren't interesting to a broader audience).